# Check if value exists in comma separated string with PHP

Tags: php

I need to check if my id exists in comma separated string.

My string is saved as `"1,2,3,4,10"` in database.

I have tried

```
$HiddenProducts = array($sqlvalue);

if (in_array(2, $HiddenProducts)) {
  echo "Available";
} else {
  echo "Not available";
}
```

It is not working. Any solutions please...

Comment: To make an array out of a string with comma separated values you need `explode()` instead of `array()`.

Comment: Why don't you use your database function to check it? And why is it stored as a string?

Comment: The fasetest way to ckeck if a value is inside a CSV is: `strpos(',' . $list . ',', ',' . $item . ',') !== FALSE;`

Answer (score 48):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array of string parts from a string, by splitting it by a certain delimiter (in this case a comma).

```
$HiddenProducts = explode(',',$sqlvalue);
if (in_array(2, $HiddenProducts)) {
  echo "Available";
} else {
  echo "Not available";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`in_array()` is in fact what you want, but you are creating your array incorrectly.

Assuming `$sqlvalue = '1,2,3,4,10'`...

```
$hiddenProducts = explode(',', $sqlvalue);
```

Then you can use `in_array()`.

Answer (score 1):

first using explode function convert the comma-separated string in to array

```
$HiddenProducts = explode(',',$sqlvalue);
```

then use in_array function to check

```
 if (in_array(2, $HiddenProducts))
   echo "Available";
else
   echo "Not available";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merely curing the symptom, let me offer a different approach.

You should probably *not* store your information in the table like that. It should be possible to let the database figure out, if some product is hidden or not. For that, you need to normalize your data properly.

Apparently, you have a table of products somewhere and some should be hidden. If this is a property `true` or `false` that belongs to every product, you can just add it to the your products table as a new column.

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE id = 2 AND hidden = 1
```

If `hidden` is not an intrinsic property of your products, you can also create a helper table  that is simply a list of product IDs.

An entry simply says that the product is hidden. If an ID is absent from the table, it's *not* hidden.